# Database schema for profile and order

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am working on a bank application in which a customer can open multiple accounts for different product types like: Insurance, Investment and annuity etc.

Each customer has a profile and we are saving that information in 12 different tables such as : Personal,Contact,Address,Affiliation,Financial,Investment,Asset,Liability,NetWorth and so on.

Now to open each account we have to collect and save same kind of information like for customer profile but we cannot overwrite the customer profile with that as we have to keep track of each accounts information when its submitted to the point when it get opened.

So in terms of solution we think either to have replica of these 12 tables for each account or to save the JSON for each table in one table only which has 12 columns for each of above table and populate UI with that.

Can somebody if have prior experience suggest us how to do this in best way.

Answer (score 1):

I would determine which information will not change between accounts. For example, `name`, `birthday`, `ssn`, etc. These constant fields can form a table called `customers`. If there are no constant fields, then you can use a placeholder id, which simply helps to associate accounts to the same user.

I would also create a table for `Accounts` and use the `account_id` as a foreign key for all your customer information that may change between accounts. Each row in the `Accounts` table will be owned by a `customer` from before.

So the relationship between customers and accounts would be one to many, and the relationship between accounts and "account specific customer info" would be one to one.

Comment: Thanks for  replying but as per my requirements information of customer profile and account profile should be saved separately. So my main concern is to use which approach:
1)Create parallel schema for account profile same as customer profile.
2)To save the JSON/XML for each table in different column which will keep changing as account profile keep updating until its not submitted.

Comment: I would lean towards not storing JSON or XML in the database. It requires more outside processing and makes it difficult to make a normalized database.

What do you mean by "store separately?" Does the information have to be in separate tables? I would think you could just identify the rows using some "information type" variable, and keep all the same kind of information in the same table.

Comment: Yes, Information have to be in separate tables. There is not a single field for same kind of information. If I do not save the JSON of each table in column then I have to create 12 parallel table and each time when schema of main table will get changed then I have change the parallel table also.